# Can't flash ESP 32 Wroom

Tags: esp32, flash

[image: esp devboard v1]

I have a new ESP32 Wroom attached to my USB and it shows up in the settings on my mac:

[image: device]

I do have another ESP thing from sparkfun which I can access via  `/dev/cu.usbserial-DN02N1D8`. This device I can flash without problems or read its mac address using `esptool.py`.

```
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____
```

So I wonder how I can flash the ESP32.

**Update**: Added a picture of my board.

Comment: does the ESP32 contain a bootloader? ...... does it show up as a serial port?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would assume that it has a boot loader. It does not show up as an additional `/dev/cu.XYZ` entry, like the ESP-Thing does (`/dev/cu.usbserial-DN02N1D8`)

Comment: @jsotola, why do you ask if it has a bootloader? as far as I know the Espressif chips have only serial upload so without a bootloader from factory they were useless

Comment: How have you attached the device? The esp wroom 32 is not soldered onto any kind of breakout board, so have you soldered wires to rx/tx?! Do you actually have a reset button? If not, there is no chance to flash it. When trying to flash without the esp being in program mode I would expect exactly what you are seeing

Comment: you might have to hold some pins hi/lo to get it to flash. on some of my esp32 modules, that's holding down the flash button, on some it grounding a certain pin (0 i think) between starting the ide upload and actually uploading it, which is a bit of a balancing act. I recommend that once you get it flashed, use an OTA method to avoid the physical challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix the problem now.

My mac has USB-C and I was using a single USB-C to USB Dongle. And the serial port never showed up on my mac:

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   5 Mar  8 10:53 /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   7 Mar  8 10:53 /dev/cu.Heinz-WirelessiAP
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   3 Mar  8 10:53 /dev/cu.MALS
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,   1 Mar  8 11:02 /dev/cu.SOC
```

As soon as I used the Satechi USB Dock the Silicon Labs USB to UART port showed up in the list:

```
[...]
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   18,  13 Mar  8 11:04 /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
```

I can now communicate with the ESP32:

```
esptool.py --port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART read_mac

esptool.py v2.6
Serial port /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART
Connecting........___
Detecting chip type... ESP32
Chip is ESP32D0WDQ6 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
MAC: XXXXXXXXX
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
MAC: XXXXXXX
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

Please note that if you'll need the [Drivers for the USB to Serial Chip from Silabs](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers).

If you do not see the device showing up you'll need to load the kernel extension:

```
sudo kextload /Library/Extensions/SiLabsUSBDriver.kext/
```

After this you might to confirm the extension in the Privacy section of the mac settings. See [this forum post](https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/forum.topic.15.15.html/cp120x_vcp_driverno-G1Bu) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Flash ESP WROOM 32**

kindly refer the link :
   https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/index.html#

Comment: Your link seems to have a typo in it.

Comment: @Besi the link is corrected